# Calling Child's scope through Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scope method defined in my Child's model `profile.rb` as follows

```
scope :fees_to, -> (fees_to) { where("fees_to <= ?", "#{fees_to}") }
```

And in the parent which is `tutor.rb` there is

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

Now in rails console i can do `Profile.all.fees_to(10)` for example and its valid. But how can i do call the `fees_to` method through the parent `Tutor`?

Basically now i am able to filter through my `profiles` in the index view of it. But what i would like to do is to filter through the `tutor` index view based on values from the child.

All help and advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: In rails console, 1, `tutor = Tutor.first` 2, `tutor.profile.fees_to(10)`.

Comment: @孙悟空 That won't work. `tutor.profile` is a specific model that will not respond to `fees_to`.

Comment: @meagar you are right, QO can create a method (not scope) in profile.rb `def fees_to (n) ...... end`. then `tutor.profile.fees_to(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense with a `has_one`. You cannot "have one" and still apply a scope to it. Scopes work on *many* records, to apply additional conditions and narrow down the result set, not specific records.

You're effectively trying to add a `where(fees_to < ?)` condition to a **specific record**, which obviously makes no sense.

If you want to use a scope via an association, it needs to be a `has_many`.

Comment: assuming i amend it to has_many, how will i go about doing it. If say in my `tutor.rb` it is `has_many :profiles` instead, would something like `tutor = Tutor.all` followed by `tutor.profiles.fees_to(10)` work?

Comment: @angkiki No, you would use `tutor = Tutor.first; tutor.profiles.fees...` .You cannot invoke an association on a collection of models, only on a specific model.  For `tutor.profiles.fees_to(10)` to work, `tutor` must be a **single specific record**, and `profiles` must be a *collection* of records, ie, a `has_many`.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way i am able to do a search or filter for my child in my Parent's index? Or is there a method just that i'm taking a totally wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

In `profile.rb`:
You can create a function like:

```
def fees_to n
   Profile.fees_to(n) # your scope is called here
end
```

Then in rails console :

```
tutor = Tutor.first
tutor.profile.fees_to(10)
```

it works like a filter. If profile's fees_to is > `n`, you will get `[]` (array empty)

**UPDATED**

```
bad =>  @tutor = Tutor.all 
good => @tutor = Tutor.includes(:profile).all # with eager loading, avoid n+1 query.
```

may be you want make loop like that:

```
@tutor.each do |tutor|   
   tutor.profile.fees_to(10) 
end
```

Comment: That would only work if a Tutor has been selected though right. So in my Tutor index if i do @tutor = Tutor.all, how do i implement the method on that?

Comment: After `@tutor = Tutor.includes(:profile).all` then, `@tutor` isn't a single object. it's a collection of tutor. method fees_to call be called only by single object. So you need a loop like that: `@tutor.each do |tutor|   tutor.profile.fees_to(10) end` I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I defined the following in my `tutor.rb`

```
def self.fees_search(n)
    @profile = Profile.fees_to(n)
    if @profile.empty?
      return Tutor.none
    else
      @profile.each do |y|
        y.tutor
      end
    end
  end
```

Not sure if its clunky or if there are redundancies, but it works perfectly fine in rails console. I can do `Tutor.fees_search(10)` and it renders all the respective Tutors accordingly.

Cheers